# multiprocessing pool.map call functions in certain order

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, map-function

How can I make multiprocessing.pool.map distribute processes in numerical order?

---

More Info:
I have a program which processes a few thousand data files, making a plot of each one.  I'm using a `multiprocessing.pool.map` to distribute each file to a processor and it works great.  Sometimes this takes a long time, and it would be nice to look at the output images as the program is running.  This would be a lot easier if the map process distributed the snapshots in order; instead, for the particular run I just executed, the first 8 snapshots analyzed were:  `0, 78, 156, 234, 312, 390, 468, 546`.  Is there a way to make it distribute them more closely to in numerical order?

---

Example:
Here's a sample code which contains the same key elements, and show's the same basic result:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

num_proc  = 4; num_calls = 20; sleeper   = 0.1

def SomeFunc(arg):
    time.sleep(sleeper)
    print "%5d" % (arg),
    sys.stdout.flush()     # otherwise doesn't print properly on single line

proc_pool = Pool(num_proc)
proc_pool.map( SomeFunc, range(num_calls) )
```

Yields:

```
   0  4  2  6   1   5   3   7   8  10  12  14  13  11   9  15  16  18  17  19
```

---

### Answer:

From @Hayden: Use the 'chunksize' parameter, `def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None)`.

**More Info**:
The `chunksize` determines how many iterations are allocated to each processor at a time.  My example above, for instance, uses a chunksize of 2---which means that each processor goes off and does its thing for 2 iterations of the function, then comes back for more ('check-in').  The trade-off behind chunksize is that there is overhead for the 'check-in' when the processor has to sync up with the others---suggesting you want a **large chunksize**.  On the other hand, if you have large chunks, then one processor might finish its chunk while another-one has a long time left to go---so you should use a **small chunksize**.  I guess the additional useful information is how much range there is, in how long each function call can take.  If they really should all take the same amount of time - it's way more efficient to use a large chunk size.  On the other hand, if some function calls could take twice as long as others, you want a small chunksize so that processors aren't caught waiting.

For my problem, every function call should take very close to the same amount of time (I think), so if I want the processes to be called in order, I'm going to sacrifice efficiency because of the check-in overhead.

Comment: What do you use to plot the data?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic I don't see how it's relevant, but from inside `SomeFunc` I would call another function, e.g. `PlotFunc()` which produces an image with `matplotlib` and `pyplot` and saves it to disk.

Comment: Is it possible to do some preprocessing in parallel and then plot in sequence?

Comment: Ah, I see - Not really, the majority of computational time is just in reading the files so I would have to wait for 90% of the total-time to be completed before plotting anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason that this occurs is because each process is given a predefined amount of work to do at the start of the call to map which is dependant on the `chunksize`. We can work out the default `chunksize` by looking at the source for [pool.map](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c54def5947c/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l305)

```
chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)
if extra:
  chunksize += 1
```

So for a range of 20, and with 4 processes, we will get a `chunksize` of 2.

If we modify your code to reflect this we should get similar results to the results you are getting now:

`proc_pool.map(SomeFunc, range(num_calls), chunksize=2)`

This yields the output:

`0    2    6    4     1     7     5     3     8    10    12    14     9    13    15    11    16    18    17    19`

Now, setting the `chunksize=1` will ensure that each process within the pool will only be given one task at a time.

`proc_pool.map(SomeFunc, range(num_calls), chunksize=1)`

This should ensure a reasonably good numerical ordering compared to that when not specifying a chunksize. For example a chunksize of 1 yields the output:

`0    1    2    3     4     5     6     7     9    10     8    11    13    12    15    14    16    17    19    18`

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  Do you have any insights into why they choose this chunksize algorithm?  Or in general, what factors should be considered for performance optimization?  (It doesn't seem like, in my case, the chunksize would have any effect on performance)

Comment: Can I ask a question? By setting chuncksize = 1, is this pool.map function run algorithm simultaneously? or it will kick off few workers, but they will do things in order? I dont quite understand "block" in the documentation..

Answer (score 1):

What about changing `map` to `imap`:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

num_proc = 4
num_calls = 20
sleeper = 0.1

def SomeFunc(arg):
    time.sleep(sleeper)
    print "%s %5d" % (os.getpid(), arg)
    return arg

proc_pool = Pool(num_proc)
list(proc_pool.imap(SomeFunc, range(num_calls)))
```

The reason maybe that the default `chunksize` of `imap` is 1, so it may not run as far as `map`.